# ConnectWise API getting Invalid Token response

Tags: json, rest, api

I am trying to get ConnectWise records using ConnectWise API like in the image below

[image]

and

[image]

but every time I send the request I am getting an Invalid Token response in Postman. I tried changing many things but not getting proper output. when I send a request for company info I am getting this.

[image]

I am new to the ConnectWise APIs if you have knowledge in ConnectWise API then please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you switch the **v4_6_release** in your URL to **v2018_6** because your API call for **companyinfo** shows that Codebase is **v2018_6**.

then also if it's not work then change your API call url. You should not have **api-na.myconnectwise.net** and instead have **api-eu.myconnectwise.net**. That should route to the correct company and correct this issue.

Comment: how do I know which URL I have to use? when I call for company info it gives me SiteUrl as api-na.myconnectwise.net like in the last image.